# Why is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Why is $\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0}$?

We can re-write the LHS as

$$\left(\lim_{h \to 0} 0\right) \cdot \left( \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \right)$$
$$0 \cdot \left( \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \right)$$

the term in the brackets is undefined, since $1 / h$ does not have a limit at $0$.

I am going through Spivak derivatives chapter right now, so would appreciate argumentation in a basic context.

The above was supposed to be a derivation of a derivative of a constant function $f(x) = c$.

Comment: "We can re-write the LHS as" Are you sure? There's a crucial assumption that needs to be satisfied here; check your text again ...

Comment: Try using the definition of limits directly, rather than fancy theorems.

Comment: yikes, you are right, jumped a step

Comment: Because for example $\frac{0}{0.1}=0,\ \frac{0}{0.01}=0,\ \frac{0}{0.001}=0\ $ etc, and also, $\frac{0}{-0.1}=0,\ \frac{0}{-0.01}=0,\ \frac{0}{-0.001}=0\ $ etc.

Comment: @AdamRubinson picking the same "test points", I guess $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(\pi/x)=0$?

Comment: Oh I see... yeah but your comment is sort of a can of worms about test cases. Obviously you need to consider the qualitative properties of the graph of the function. I was just giving some preliminary test cases to see why the result in the title *might* be true...

Comment: it is indeed correct that dividing zero by anything is a zero, but here (if we assume that the gibberish I wrote is correct for a second), you are multiplying a zero by something that is undefined.

Comment: @Naz "dividing $0$ by anything" **other than** by $0$, because division by zero is not defined.

Comment: @AdamRubinson That's why I forbid my students to use "sampling" to try to find limits. Being confident requires having a good sense of how the function behaves qualitatively, even if not quantitatively... but often that is what one is trying to figure out with limits. They don't have a good sense of when sampling is likely to mislead, and when it won't, so best not to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the definition of the limit: you actually can't split the limit like that as that second limit clearly diverges!

For $h\ne0$, $\frac{0}{h}=0$

So $\forall ɛ >0, \exists δ>0$ s.t $ 0<|h|<δ \implies  |0|<ɛ$

But clearly, for any positive ɛ, that inequality is arbitrarily true, so I could just take $δ=1$ and that proves by the definition of the limit that $\lim_{h\to\ 0} (\frac{0}{h})= 0$

Comment: this is perfect. I was going to write out definition of the limit directly like this

Answer (score 3):

Splitting the limit of a product into the product of limits is only allowed if both limits exist. Since the second limit doesn't exist, you cannot rewrite it like that.

The limit is $0$ because your limit point only depends on the points ''around'' zero. And then $\frac{0}{h}=0$. So in other words:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{0}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}0=0.$$

Edit: This last part is maybe a bit vague. The definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ is:
$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(0<|x-a|\leq\delta\Longrightarrow|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon).$$

Since $0<|x-a|$, we get by applying that to your problem that we can substitute $\frac{0}{h}$ by $0$. It expresses that the value of $f$ at $a$ has no influence on the limit.

Answer (score 2):

1. The limit of a product is the product of the limits **if they both exist**. You cannot apply this limit rule/law to the limit of $0\cdot \frac{1}{h}$ as $h\to $, because the second factor's limit does not exist.
2. Remember that the value of a limit as $h\to 0$ cares only about what happens *near* $0$, and not what happens *at* $0$. This gives the following limit law that a lot of textbooks use but do not state explicitly:

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions defined on an open interval $I$ containing $a$, except perhaps at $a$, and that for every $x$ in $I$, except perhaps $x=a$, we have $f(x)=g(x)$. Then $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$
> in that either neither limit exists, or else they both exist and are equal.

We can apply this rule to the function $f(h)=\frac{0}{h}$ defined everywhere but at $h=0$, and the constant function $g(h)=0$, to conclude the limit equals $0$.